# Set eventual consistency (late commit) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

Consider the following situation: You want to update the number of page views of each profile in your system. This action is very frequent, as almost all visits to your website result in a page view incremental.

The basic way is *update Users set page_views=page_views+1*. But this is totally not optimal because we don't really need instant update (1 hour late is ok). **Is there any other way in MySQL to postpone a sequence of updates, and make cumulative updates at a later time?**

I myself tried another method: storing a counter (# of increments) for each profile. But this also results in handling a few thousands of small files, and I think that the disk IO  cost (even if a deep tree-structure for files is applied) would probably exceed the database.

**What is your suggestion for this problem (other than MySQL)?**

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459395/deferring-frequent-updates-in-mysql) help at all?

Comment: This is very helpful. Definitively I'll try it ;) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

To improve performance you could store your page view data in a [MEMORY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html) table - this is super fast but temporary, the table only persists while the server is running - on restart it will be empty...

You could then create an [EVENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) to update a table that will persist the data on a timed basis. This would help improve performance a little with the risk that, should the server go down, only the number of visits since the last run of the event would be lost.

Comment: Memory table isn't durable, so I think it results in some overheads to manipulate the date in and out. But it's promising!

For late method. I develop a habit when using Database is to utilize nothing but regular key (no event, no trigger, no procedure, no foreign key ...) because it would become so difficult to scale.

Answer (score 1):

The link posted by James via the comment to your question, wherein lies an accepted answer with another comment about memcached was my first thought also. Just store the profileIds in memcached then you could set up a cron to run every 15 minutes and grab all the entries then issue the updates to MySQL in a batch, but there are a few things to consider.

1. When you run the batch script to grab the ids out of memcached, you will have to ensure you remove all entries which have been parsed, otherwise you run the risk of counting the same profile views multiple times.
2. Being that memcache doesn't support wildcard searching via keys, and that you will have to purge existing keys for the reason stated in #1, you will probably have to setup a separate memcache server pool dedicated for the sole purpose of tracking profile ids, so you don't end up purging cached values which have no relation to profile view tracking. However, you could avoid this by storing the profileId and a timestamp within the value payload, then have your batch script step through each entry and check the timestamp, if it's within the time range you specified, add it to queue to be updated, and once you hit the upper limit of your time range, the script stops.

Another option may be to parse your access logs. If user profiles are in a known location like `/myapp/profile/1234`, you could parse for this pattern and add profile views this way. I ended up having to go this route for advertiser tracking, as it ended up being the only repeatable way to generate billing numbers. If they had any billing disputes we would offer to send them the access logs and parse for themselves.